# Check whether two strings are anagrams

Tags: beginner, rust

Inspired by [Monday's Reddit daily programmer challenge](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/52enht/20160912_challenge_283_easy_anagram_detector/), I wrote a function to check whether two strings are anagrams. It doesn't take the same input as the challenge, though, since I don't want to handle user input (yet).

For the lazy ones, the task is to write a function that checks whether the letters in the first word can be shuffled (and upcased/downcased) to create the second word. Punctuation and whitespace isn't important.

This is more or less the first code I've written in Rust, so *any* kind of feedback is welcome:

```
/// Returns the sorted alphabetic symbols of a string in lowercase.
fn normalize(s : &str) -> Vec<char> {
    let mut characters : Vec<char> = s.to_lowercase()
        .chars()
        .filter(|x| x.is_alphabetic())
        .collect();
    characters.sort();
    characters
}

/// Returns true if the sets of alphabetic symbols coincide.
pub fn is_anagram(a : &str, b : &str) -> bool{
    normalize(a) == normalize(b)
}

#[test]
fn is_anagram_test() {
    assert!( is_anagram("Clint Eastwood","Old West Action"));
    assert!( is_anagram("wisdom","mid sow"));
    assert!(!is_anagram("Reddit","Eat Dirt"));
    assert!( is_anagram("Schoolmaster","The classroom"));
    assert!( is_anagram("Vacation Times", "I'm Not as Active"));
    assert!( is_anagram("12431b53c11a5324", "abc"));
}
```

I'm not particularly fond of using a `mut Vec<char>` just to use `sort`, but I guess it's the same situation as in C++, where `std::sort` will also modify a container in-place. The code was written with previous experience in C++, but with the following Haskell code in mind:

```
isAnagramOf :: String -> String -> Bool
isAnagramOf = (==) `on` (sort . map toLower . filter isLetter)
```

Comment: I usually go with "What happens inside a function stays inside a function". There is no way to tell outside of ``normalize`` whether you used mutability or not. The function is pure, side effect free and re-entrant as it is. So why bother?

Comment: @BitTickler: I don't hate it. I just was kind of surprised that there are so many functions for iterators, but not a `.sorted()` for cloneable things with a total order, so I thought I missed something. But as I said, it's the same in C++ either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no space before `:` in types.
2. There is a space after the return type
3. There is a space between function arguments, after the comma.
4. `str::to_lowercase` allocates a new string. It's a potential optimization to iterate through each character and convert to lowercase. Profiling should be done if performance matters.
5. Could use itertools `sorted` to reduce some boilerplate. Does the same thing under the hood.

```
extern crate itertools;
use itertools::Itertools;

/// Returns the sorted alphabetic symbols of a string in lowercase.
fn normalize(s: &str) -> Vec<char> {
    s.chars()
        .flat_map(char::to_lowercase)
        .filter(|c| c.is_alphabetic())
        .sorted()
}

/// Returns true if the sets of alphabetic symbols coincide.
pub fn is_anagram(a: &str, b: &str) -> bool {
    normalize(a) == normalize(b)
}

#[test]
fn is_anagram_test() {
    assert!( is_anagram("Clint Eastwood", "Old West Action"));
    assert!( is_anagram("wisdom", "mid sow"));
    assert!(!is_anagram("Reddit", "Eat Dirt"));
    assert!( is_anagram("Schoolmaster", "The classroom"));
    assert!( is_anagram("Vacation Times", "I'm Not as Active"));
    assert!( is_anagram("12431b53c11a5324", "abc"));
}
```

Ultimately, you won't be able to achieve the same particular kind of elegance as the Haskell solution, but I'd hope that the performance would be better.

Comment: Do you have any source for the styling guidelines? Is there a linting program? Otherwise those are more or less primary opinion, if there isn't a "official" recommendation (see PEP8 in Python for example).

Comment: @Zeta [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt), also via the big "Format" button at the top of the [official Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/). The [style guide source](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/fmt-rfcs).